# How to fix Server DNS couldn't be found?

Tags: node.js, networking, dns

There are questions about DNS but this is a different one. I run my app on corporate server xxxxx:4000 and it works perfect on Windows. But when I try to access my app from mobile device it says that server DNS couldn't be found. Do you guys have any idea what would be the problem?

The mobile phone is on the same network and it should be able to access the app.

Comment: Perhaps try with the IP address directly for a start? (xx.xx.xx.xx:4000)

Answer (score 0):

keep ip address same but try to fill the DNS manually
as below:-

> 208.67.222.222
> 208.67.220.220

if it doesn't work then try

> 4.2.2.2